# importing project in android Studio built with eclipse and libGDX

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

First, I import the project in android studio, since my project had many modules so to avoid errors that appears, I should add some details to the gradle (dependencies ...). So, I fixed all the errors and the building of the project finished with one warning but when I tried to run the project I got many errors.

Messages of build (warnings)

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :projectNameAndroid:generateDebugSources, :projectNameAndroid:mockableAndroidJar, :projectNameAndroid:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :projectNameAndroid:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :projectNameAndroid:compileDebugSources, :projectNameAndroid:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :projectNameAndroid:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
Warning:[options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 1 mins 1.934 secs
Information:0 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

Messages of run(errors)

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [:projectNameAndroid:clean, :projectNameAndroid:generateDebugSources, :projectNameAndroid:mockableAndroidJar, :projectNameAndroid:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :projectNameAndroid:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :projectNameAndroid:assembleDebug]
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$4) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$5) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$6) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$7) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Native$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Structure$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.Structure$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3 mins 54.416 secs
Information:153 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

gradle of the project :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Gradle of java module

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7

    compile files('libs/game_lib.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-box2d.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-freetype.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-tools.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-box2d-sources.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-freetype-sources.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-sources.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-tools-sources.jar')

}
```

gradle of android module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amine.mygame"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':jungleBike')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/AdBuddiz-2.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-backend-android.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'

    compile files('libs/game_lib.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-box2d.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-freetype.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-tools.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-box2d-sources.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-freetype-sources.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-sources.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-tools-sources.jar')
}
```

Comment: Can you share your gradle build file?

Comment: @Logain I share it,thanks for helping

Comment: @amine_detter did you ever work this out?

Comment: @RussWheeler no i didn't, because all the time the project request libraries even if i put them on, and even if I built the project with libgdx and put on the source code (built with eclipse) it doesn't work. In my opinion I think there is a problem with building the gradle with a project built with eclipse and Libgdx. So I decided to continue my project with eclipse.

Comment: Hmm, I have a feeling it was due to changes in the libGDX lib, not necessarily the gradle part. Oh well, thanks for replying